# Выход за пределы массива, не понятно почему

Tags: java

Выбрасывается exeption  выход за рамки массива. Скажите пожалуйста,что неправильно?

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Point {
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static ArrayList<Integer> interset(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4) {
        int ax = Math.max(x1, x3);
        int bx = Math.min(x2, x4);
        int ay = Math.max(y1, y3);
        int by = Math.min(y2, y4);
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);

        if (bx < ax || by < ay) {
            return a;
        } else {
            a.add(ax);
            a.add(bx);
            a.add(ay);
            a.add(by);
            return a;
        }
    }
    public static int square(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        return ((x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1));
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6;
        x1 = scanner.nextInt();
        y1 = scanner.nextInt();
        x2 = scanner.nextInt();
        y2 = scanner.nextInt();
        x3 = scanner.nextInt();
        y3 = scanner.nextInt();
        x4 = scanner.nextInt();
        y4 = scanner.nextInt();
        x5 = scanner.nextInt();
        y5 = scanner.nextInt();
        x6 = scanner.nextInt();
        y6 = scanner.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a = new ArrayList<Integer>(interset(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4));
        b = new ArrayList<Integer>(interset(x1, y1, x2, y2, x5, y5, x6, y6));
        c = new ArrayList<Integer>(interset(a.get(0), a.get(1), a.get(2), a.get(3), b.get(0), b.get(1), b.get(2), b.get(3)));
        if (square(x1, y1, x2, y2) > square(a.get(0), a.get(1), a.get(2), a.get(3)) + square(b.get(0), b.get(1), b.get(2), b.get(3)) - square(c.get(0), c.get(1), c.get(2), c.get(3)))
        {
            System.out.print("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);` список все-равно пустой. Попробуйте сразу же после его создания обратиться к, например, первому элементу. Такое ощущение, что вы хотели по умолчанию сделать список на 4 `null` элемента. Угадал?

Comment: да, так и хотела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что конструктор [public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) создаст внутри списка массив указанного размера, но не заполнит его значениями по умолчанию, поэтому по сути список будет без элементов.

Поэтому, у вас и происходила ошибка.

Измените код заполнения списка как:

```
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(4, 0));
        if (bx < ax || by < ay) {
            return a;
        } else {
            a.set(0, ax);
            a.set(1, bx);
            a.set(2, ay);
            a.set(3, by);
            return a;
        }
```

Если в списке нужны именно `null`, то `Collections.nCopies(4, null)`

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте логику `if` внутри метода `interset`. Например, при вводе первых чисел `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8` промежуточные значения посчитаются как `ax = 5, bx = 3, ay = 6, by = 4` и следовательно, вставка в массив не будет вызвана вовсе (так как `bx < ax`).